# generic repository to access database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

Hi I want to create a generic `Repository` class that will access database. It will be extended by typed repositories

```
public abstract class Repository<T>
{
    protected MyContext ctx = null;

    public Repository()
    {
        if (this.ctx == null)
        {
            this.ctx = new MyContext();
        }
    }

    public T FindById(int id)
    {
        return this.ctx.T.Single(s => s.Id == id);
    }
}
```

The only problem with this is that the `T` class is not recognized in `this.ctx.T`. I understand why, there is no such collection in my context. Can I solve this problem somehow ?

Comment: What is the type of MyContext? Is it generated by Entity Framework or some other ORM library?

Comment: @JesseCarter it is generated by Entity Framework

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Entity Framework you can use [DbContext.Set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696521(v=vs.103).aspx) method:

```
this.ctx.Set<T>()
```

Comment: @Fixus you can create an interface (`IEntity`) containing this filed, add constraint `where T : class, IEntity` and implement this interface in all classes you need to query by `Id`